# Rails not rendering template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails application that was originally set up for Rails API only, however, I need to set up a permalink page through Rails model-view-controller.

I defined a route

```
get 'posts/:id', :to => 'posts#display'
```

In posts controller

```
def display
  render "show"
end
```

In /views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

When I hit the URL in browser: `localhost:3000/posts/1` I would expect to just see the "Hello" rendered from the view

However, I'm just getting a blank text.

From the Rails server log

```
Started GET "/posts/1" for ::1 at 2022-01-28 18:08:19 -0500
Processing by PostsController#display as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 451)
```

I'm not sure if the assets are not compiling?

Versions:

```
ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1.3
```

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging here - look the the actual raw response in the network tab in your browser and check the rails logs for any clues as to what's going on. On a side note this code is pretty awful. Just stock with the conventions and declare a normal show route.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-a-single-article

Comment: Firstly remove the render statement, that is not needed, secondly, either rename the method to show and adjust the route or rename the template to display.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the layout that yields the views, also as per my comment on your question, rename the method to show, change the route to match and remove the render statement from the controller action.

You have not posted nearly enough of your code to provide a full solution but your controller can specify which layout to use with the layout command or if descending from application controller then make sure `application_controller.rb` is specifying which layout to use and check the yield statement in that layout template.

Create the layout if you don't have one
You seem to be missing Rails standard conventions and if you fight them you'll loose

route should become

```
resources :posts, only: [:show]
```

your controller should be either

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

or

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  layout "posts"

  def show
  end
end
```

and you need to check the `application_layout.html.erb` in the `views/layouts` folder and ensure that it has a yield statement in the body or if you use the second controller option that defines a different layout then you will need to create that layout and again ensure that after the head section you have a body and you call yield in that. Ensure that you use all the correct headers in the head section

a typical layout looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Css menu</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

If you do not have the correct `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` declarations your browser won't know what to do

if you are providing a specific `posts_layout.html.erb` in the `views/layouts` folder to handle the specific layout declared in my second posts controller example you will need to just bear in mind that any other controllers needing to render views will need to specify which layout to use so I would stick to the `application_layout.html.erb` and make sure that it is being used in the `application_controller.rb`

Rails will automatically render the template named after the action and format so no need to call render in the controllers action.